# How to get delete-button behavior in vim?

Tags: vim, del

When using vim in insert mode (or not using vim at all), pressing the delete-button deletes a character TO THE RIGHT of the cursor. How can I get this behavior in vim when in normal mode?
Pressing x is not the right answer as it deletes the selected character, not the character to the right.

Answer (score 1):

In the Insert mode it's just for you the cursor looks "kinda between characters". But in fact, your computer sees it being right on the character you are deleting.

In the Normal mode you normally have the bar-cursor, so it looks the way it works.

Now, of course, you can remap your "x" to delete the char to the right, but it will only add a confusion. So, please, don't. Train your mind to see the things in the proper light instead.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, let's say you want to put the cursor at the end of a line and press delete in order to move up the following row. You can't do that in normal mode, unless i missed something?

Comment: @HenrikLeijon Not sure if I get you right, but is it `J`?